# tf-agents ValueError: Received a mix of batched and unbatched Tensors, or Tensors are not compatible with Specs

Tags: python, tensorflow, buffer, specifications, agent

I basically want to train a dqn agent starting from a pre-filled replay buffer with already existing experience. However, I do not know how to get the _add_batch() method of my replay buffer to work.
Here the initialization of the buffer:

```
replay_buffer = tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
        agent.collect_data_spec,
        batch_size=tf_env.batch_size,
        max_length=rb_capacity)
```

Where agent.collect_data_spec is:

```
Trajectory(
{'action': BoundedTensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name='action', minimum=array(0), maximum=array(3)),
 'discount': BoundedTensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='discount', minimum=array(0., dtype=float32), maximum=array(1., dtype=float32)),
 'next_step_type': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name='step_type'),
 'observation': DictWrapper({'instances': BoundedTensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float64, name='instances', minimum=array([0.]), maximum=array([8.])), 'workload': BoundedTensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float64, name='workload', minimum=array([0.]), maximum=array(1.79769313e+308)), 'pressure': BoundedTensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float64, name='pressure', minimum=array([0.]), maximum=array(1.79769313e+308)), 'q': BoundedTensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float64, name='q', minimum=array([0.]), maximum=array(1.79769313e+308)), 'utilization': BoundedTensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float64, name='utilization', minimum=array([0.]), maximum=array([1.]))}),
 'policy_info': (),
 'reward': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='reward'),
 'step_type': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name='step_type')})
```

batch_size=tf_env.batch_size = 1024
and max_length=rb_capacity = 3000

Every instance of "array" used to create the tensors is basically a numpy.array starting from the values from the pre-existing experience that I want to put in the replay buffer:

```
# Create tensors for every field
    action_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(action_array, dtype=tf.int64)
    instances_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(instances_array, dtype=tf.float64) 
    pressure_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(pressure_array, dtype=tf.float64)
    q_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(q_array, dtype=tf.float64)
    utilization_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(utilization_array, dtype=tf.float64)
    workload_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(workload_array, dtype=tf.float64)
    reward_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(reward_array, dtype=tf.float32)
    discount_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(discount_array, dtype=tf.float32)
```

And here's how the trajectory is generated:

```
# Generate a trajectory object
    trajectory = tf_agents.trajectories.first(
      observation={
        "instances": instances_tensor,
        "pressure": pressure_tensor,
        "q": q_tensor,
        "utilization": utilization_tensor,
        "workload": workload_tensor
      },
      action=action_tensor,
      policy_info=(),
      reward=reward_tensor,
      discount=discount_tensor
    )
```

Then I just call:

```
replay_buffer.add_batch(trajectory)
```

Which then raises the error:

```
ValueError: Received a mix of batched and unbatched Tensors, or Tensors are not compatible with Specs.  num_outer_dims: 1.
Saw tensor_shapes:
   [TensorShape([1]), TensorShape([]), TensorShape([]), TensorShape([]), TensorShape([]), TensorShape([]), TensorShape([1]), TensorShape([1]), TensorShape([1]), TensorShape([1])]
And spec_shapes:
   [TensorShape([]), TensorShape([1]), TensorShape([1]), TensorShape([1]), TensorShape([1]), TensorShape([1]), TensorShape([]), TensorShape([]), TensorShape([]), TensorShape([])]
```

All i want to do is generate some (not many) trajectories and put them in the replay buffer to help the agent learn faster. I am confused and I totally cannot see where the issue is.
I'm very grateful for every little bit of help I can get. :)